# Juju - Failed ssh connection

Tags: juju, maas

I am using ubuntu 14.04.02 server. Have 4 nodes allocated to root. Now I had this problem and when I try to ssh to a machine to check logs, the ssh connection fails. **All of the machines I use are all Virtual Machines.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't know if this is important but do I need to do something in here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It's getting difficult to get working mysql+wordpress, I am doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the MAAS IP to /etc/resolv.conf as a nameserver, but that will get overwritten eventually. How to make it permanent depends on how your network is setup and is out of scope for this question. But it should get you going for now.

Alternatively, and temporarily (because the IP will change), you can also just add the node4.maas name to /etc/hosts with its IP. That IP you can get in the MAAS node listing page and clicking on the node name, or by running "dig @ +short node4.maas".